# Configure django-tenants to write and read from AzureStorage

Tags: django, azure, django-storage, django-tenants

As per the django-tenants docs for file handling. I've done everything but if i include this line. 
`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "django_tenants.files.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage"` 
This will use local file storage path for storage. And when i checked TenantFileSystemStorage this class is inherited from FileSystemStorage. How can i configue TenantFileSystemStorage to use AzureStorage? I don't think any docs available to achieve this. Any help on this is much appreciated. 
 
 **Requirements:** Upload should save any file to azure and also read from azure.